# AngularJS 1. Trying to implement a checkbox beside field-names being written in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

The code you see below works 100% but the problem is I am trying to implement a checkbox list into the single-page application. I am new to angular

```
  <select  size="10"  class="form-control" name="brandSelector" 
 multiple="multiple" ng-model="brandGroup.brand_ids" ng-options="b._id as '' 
+ b.name+' - '+b.division_name for b in brands">.
```

I tried finding a solution on the internet and found this block of code but that is just writing in the name, the other piece of code above pulls data in from somewhere. How do I implement a checkbox without hassle? Thank you

```
 <div>
   <input type="checkbox" name="brandSelector" value="">
 <label>&nbsp;Ted Baker Kids - Hudson</label></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'How do I implement a checkbox without hassle'?

Comment: how do implement a checkbox while using the ng-options ?